# Zurb Foundation 6 not working on Codeigniter

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am currently running Foundation 5 on Codeigniter, and it works. Now i'm trying to install Foundation 6 ([the CSS version](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html#css-download)) which doesn't want to work.

I've set up a simple page called `prova-foundation` and here is the code ([as illustrated here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html#html-starter-template)):

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation Starter Template</title>
    <?php echo link_tag('css/foundation-6/foundation.css?ver=1.1'); ?>
    <?php echo link_tag('css/foundation-6/app.css?ver=1.1'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/foundation-6/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/foundation-6/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/foundation-6/foundation.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

But i get the following errors in Firebug (Firefox latest version 44.0.2):

```
SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier
class AccordionMenu {
foundation.js (linea 1751, col 2)

TypeError: $(...).foundation is not a function
$(document).foundation();
prova-foundation# (linea 16, col 7)
```

And Foundation doesn't work...
All the `<script>` and `css` links are correct. If i open each one of them in the browser, the corresponding file is loaded.

What's wrong with my page? ([i've set up a test page here](https://www.racebooking.net/it/moto/prova-foundation#))

Comment: Have you set your base url? It could be you may have left it blank on config.php and did you autoload url helper.

Comment: Yes. Codeigniter config works, because it's the same directory where i'm currently running Foundation 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `foundation.js` file you have included was written in **ES6**. In **Foundation 6.2** the JavaScript was rewritten with **ES6**. It needs to be transpiled to **ES5** using [**Babel**](http://babeljs.io/) in order to work in the browser. This is not something you should have to do if you are downloading the CSS versions. That should be done before it's made available for download.

I have opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/8353) to get this resolved.

Before this is resolved, here are two options you have to get it working:

1. Copy and paste the code from your `foundation.js` file [here](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015&code=) and copy paste the resulting, transpiled code back in your `foundation.js` file and save it.
2. Download the **Complete** version from http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download/ you can get the transpiled `foundation.js` and `foundation.min.js` files. It appears the **Essential** download is messed up but the **Complete** download is working.

Comment: For the first time in my life i don't feel dumb! Thank you